# Assistance with good starting references for tools like Maven, ANT Build, etc

Tags: java, maven, ant

Ok Spare me for this post. I am a newbie like the guy here:  [Importance of tools like Ant Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589566/importance-of-tools-like-ant-maven)
But i want to really start learning specially ant scripts and maven. I went on their respective project sites but could not find basic documentation from where i should start with.

I would appreciate your time if you could direct me to some simple tutorials/articles that explain basic usage of ant and maven. Specially if there is some basic example that really explains how well maven and/or ant are used and provide benefits over static build process.

I am thinking to setup a local repository over my same machine, should i go with redmine or SVN, any recommendation for a newbie please, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, starting with a specially written book would probably be the best idea if you really want to understand well. But to give you a kick start, this resource was really helpful to me:

[10 Minutes Guide to Ant](http://www.roseindia.net/jboss/10_minutes_guide_to_ant.shtml)

It will give you step by step approach how to setup a test project for a complete newbie.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, this was absolutely what i wanted to have. I often to refer to this site, btw i also find this: http://www.roseindia.net/maven2/ this would give me good kick start, thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

Don't learn both. Choose one of them. But I would suggest that you use the best from both worlds with http://gradle.org/ .

Comment: btw. gradle has a nice user guide http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide.html

Comment: thanks but seniors in my college told me if i am into java, i should definitely have both maven and ant listed on my resume. So may be it is wise to first start with ant, then maven, and then best of both worlds solution, don't you think?

Comment: Well, I actually don't agree with ollins. I'd say investigate both. They both have their strengths and weaknesses. They both do certain things really well. We actually use both at our IT shop. I generally look to the Ant Developer's Handbook (I have a hard copy). It has been really good as an Ant resource.

Comment: Okay, if you want to have it on your CV then learn both or all three.  Most of existing projects using maven or ant. But a lot of open source projects switching to gradle (springframework for example) If you want a build system for a project use gradle .

Comment: @ChrisAldrich, where can i find this handbook please? Also does it start from basic to advance or assumes one knows many things before hand? btw uptil now i have only used Eclipse and Netbeans for making basic GUI's, but primarily Eclipse where i know how to add libraries in build path, but never ever have any experience with ant/build etc.
But i have used a project that was based on ant, it was just click and done, nothing much on my part though... please recommend any good starting resource please

Comment: online http://ant.apache.org/resources.html

Comment: I have this book (but is a little bit outdated) http://www.amazon.com/Java-Development-Ant-Erik-Hatcher/dp/1930110588/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1328805133&sr=8-2

Comment: @ollins, thanks i will check this book in the library

Comment: This is the book from Amazon (http://www.amazon.com/Ant-Developers-Handbook-Alan-Williamson/dp/0672324261/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1328825346&sr=8-1). You can probably find it through your library as well.